# How to pass formData with file input to axios using Put request

Tags: reactjs, axios, laravel-8, put

I am currently working on a project using Laravel 8 and React.

I'm trying to update record in my table using axios.

Creating record works fine (I used formdata and passed to axios.post())

Now for update part I use axios.put()

I have a form with (same fields as create form) input text fields and file input field. I use state to store values in them on inputchange.

While I try to save all the fields value to formdata and pass the form data, in the php controller, I see no data in request parameter.

When I pass the state instead of formdata, I see the text fields data in request parameter but not the file input.

How should I pass all the formdata in axios.put